# QT5 moc, qrc, and ui files in the "generated files" section say they have been moved or removed

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, header-files

I installed QT5 addin for Visual Studio 2013 and created a project.  I started creating my GUI (which I will need to figure out how to process, but that's another story all together) and when I open up the project, there's a field called "generated files" that has moc_, qrc_, and ui_ prefixed files that are referenced by the cpp file in "sources", but they have little red circles next to them and when I try to open them it says "The document cannot be opened. It has been renamed, deleted or moved." I'm not sure what I did wrong or if this is even that big of an issue.  the ui file opened and I was able to pull up the gui for designing my gui.  Is there a way to remedy this?

Edit: I built the solution and it populated the ui header with the stuff from my GUI.  I suppose I should have tried to build before I started posting questions all over the internet.

Comment: I'm not using *Visual Studion* while writing *Qt*-Applications. So I doesn't know much about this issue. Basically I thing you should not edit this files. *Qt Creator* dosent show them at all. Maybe it is an imperfection of the *Qt*-integration in *VS*. Does everything work?

Comment: Not really.  For example, the ui header file is included like `#include "ui_auctionapp.h"` but when I go to look at this header file it doesn't exist, and the other include statement `#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>` isn't working either and I don't know how to resolve the include settings.  There are tons of things underlined red because I assume it needs the headers it included.

Comment: *"the ui header file is included like #include "ui_auctionapp.h" but when I go to look at this header file it doesn't exist"* - You say that you cannot open it. But does the compiler fail to read it too? And `#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>` seems wrong to me. It should be `#include <QMainWindow>`. Like written [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html) or [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html).

Comment: I'm going to ignore it for now.  I have created my gui I want, but how do I implement it in my main?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Maybe you should read some [examples of Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) if you doesn't know how to work with it. You may also find some good tutorials with google or something else.